# Understanding the role of sales tax in problems involving prices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know what I should do in an algebraic calculation when there is sales tax mentioned. For example, let us suppose that the retail price of shirt is $R$ dollars, and  the price including sales tax is $T$ dollars. Then sales tax as a percent is which number?

When there is sales tax mentioned, what does it mean? For example, let's say that the retail price for a computer is $1000$ dollars, and sales tax is $200$. Should I add or subtract? Does it mean that when I am buying a computer, should I also pay for customs? I don't know business terms well, that's why I would like to clarify this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sales tax works by adding to the price of a purchase some percentage of that price.

Let's say you buy a Gucci T-shirt for $50, at a 5% sales tax rate. The cost is

$$\$50 + \frac{5}{100} \cdot \$50 = \$52.50.$$

But notice how $\$50$ appears twice -- we can use the distributive rule to back this out!

$$\$50 \left(1+\frac{5}{100}\right) = \$52.50.$$

Now let's say we don't know the sales tax rate $t$, but we do know the original price $P$ and final price $F$.

Then, $$ P\left(1 + \frac{t}{100}\right) = F.$$

Solving for this, we find $$\left(1+\frac{t}{100}\right) = \frac{F}{P}\\ \frac{t}{100} = \frac{F}{P}-1 \\
t = 100\left(\frac{F}{P}-1\right).$$

---

Therefore, sales tax is defined a percent of the **original** cost of the purchase. Now, sales tax will *also* be a percent of the **final** cost.

Notice for our T-shirt example, the sales tax is 5% of the original cost, but it is
$$ \frac{\$2.50}{\$52.50}\cdot 100 \approx 4.762 \%$$

of our total cost.

So what does this mean? If our shirt costs $\$50 + \$2.50 = \$52.50$, then the percentage that is sales tax is the total amount of sales tax $\$2.50$ divided by the total cost of the shirt $\$52.50$. So, in other words,

$$\textrm{total percent of purchase attributed to tax} = \frac{\$2.50}{\$50 + \$2.50} \cdot 100.$$

Comment: so it means that if  retail price is $10$ and  tax is $20$, i should add $10+10*20/100$?

Comment: Yes, if tax is 20%, then you should add another 20% of $10.

Comment: but in questions  there is not given percentage sign\

Comment: Maybe it's a typo.

Comment: here it is http://vimeo.com/6479095

Comment: @dato Read my edits.